# Creating form setting in VB Programmatically

Tags: vb.net, settings, vb.net-2010

My question is how to create a new form setting in vb.net language to save data Programmatically.

For example when i click button it will create the setting which it,s name is the text of the textbox1.

is this possible and how.
And is there any functions which can save data when program is closed?

Comment: but can i do that Programmatically?

Comment: First Google hit: [How to: Persist User Settings in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/app-settings/how-to-persist-user-settings)

Comment: WHICH VB language? It can't be both VBA and VB.NET! They are not the same in this.

Comment: i,am sorry it,s vb.net

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to know how to do this programmatically because your use case does not seem to require programmatic access to settings if you could simply link textbox1 to a setting in the IDE.

Comment: i want it as i will dealing with alot of values which i can't get number of them

Comment: You could create a class to hold the data and just serialize them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own settings-class which inherits [`ApplicationSettingsBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase?view=netframework-4.7.1):

```
Imports System.Configuration

Public Class MyUserSettings
    Inherits ApplicationSettingsBase
    <UserScopedSetting()> _
    <DefaultSettingValue("white")> _
    Public Property BackgroundColor() As Color
        Get
            BackgroundColor = Me("BackgroundColor")
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            Me("BackgroundColor") = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

**Save the settings:**

```
Dim Mus As New MyUserSettings
Mus.BackgroundColor = Color.AliceBlue
Mus.Save()
```

**Load the settings:**

```
Dim Mus As New MyUserSettings
MessageBox.Show(Mus.BackgroundColor.ToString)
```

Source: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-application-settings)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that through the form designer.

Go to the ApplicationSettings / PropertyBinding and click the ... button.

[image]

Then assign a New setting to the Text property by clicking here:

[image]

.Net takes care of making the settings save automatically when the program exits.  If you want to force it to save, just call `My.Settings.Save()`

Comment: The question was asking how to do this programmatically, not via the IDE.

Comment: Ah!  I missed that part of the question.  In that case, you could do this once and then analyze the code it generates to see how it does it.  Then work it out from there how to add more.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way in VBA is a standard functions to save setting to Registry:

```
Call SaveSetting(appName, Section, Key, Value)

Value = GetSetting(appName, Section, Key)
```

Just put them in form constructor and form destructor:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
...
end sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate() 
...
end sub
```